# How can i go 1 item further or back in a list

Tags: android, list, math, numbers

I'm developing an Android app and I have a little question. Let me explain the goal first:

The goal is that the user has multiple items: eg. Item 1, Item 2 and Item 3. 
Every item has subitems: eg. Subitem 1, Subitem 2, Subitem 3.

So for example the user selects:  Subitem 2 within Item 3.
Now the question is: Can i go back and forward in items without clicking them?

I all ready have an option to read the numbers from the string and edit them.

But what I want is that the subitem can't go further then 1~3, and if the item is 1 and the subitem is 3 and the next btn is pressed that it changes the selection to item 2 and subitem 1. 
If i make my self clear enough, if i do there must be a vice versa option!!! 
So if the item is 2 and the subitem is 1 and the back btn is pressed the item is 1 and the subitem is 3.

2 Little notes, but very important:
Now the item's can't go higher then 1~10 
And the subitem's can't go higher then 1~3.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
int weeknr;
                 int trainingnr;
                 weeknr = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(
                 week.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "")).replace(" ", ""));
                 trainingnr = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(
                 training.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "")).replace(" ",
                 ""));

                 if (weeknr > 0 && trainingnr > 0) {
                 week = "Week " + String.valueOf(weeknr - 1);
                 if (trainingnr != 1 && weeknr >1) {
                 trainingnr = 3;
                 weeknr = weeknr - 1;
                 }
                 training = "Training " + String.valueOf(trainingnr - 1);
                 trainingSelected = "";
                 trainingSelected = week + "_" + training;
                 playTraining();
```

If you are dutch or a friend of yours is (because the app and every thing releated to the app is dutch too) AND you have the best/working answer, you can get a Premium code for this app!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing this:

```
int weeknr;
                 int trainingnr;
                 weeknr = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(
                 week.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "")).replace(" ", ""));
                 trainingnr = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(
                 training.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "")).replace(" ",
                 ""));

                 if (weeknr == 10) {
                     Log.d("TrainingControl", "Week is equal to 10");

                     if (trainingnr == 3) {
                         Log.d("TrainingControl", "Training is equal to 3");
                         Toast.makeText(
                                 MainActivity.this,
                                 "Dit is de laatste training, u kunt niet verder naar de volgende",
                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 


                     }else if(trainingnr < 3){
                         Log.d("TrainingControl", "Training is less then 3");
                         training = "Training " + String.valueOf(trainingnr + 1);
                     }


                 } else if(weeknr < 10){
                     Log.d("TrainingControl", "Week is less then 10");
                     //Week +1 if training equals 3 and the week is less then 10
                     if (trainingnr == 3) {
                         Log.d("TrainingControl", "Training is equal to 3");
                         week = "Week " + String.valueOf(weeknr + 1);
                         training = "Training " +1;
                     }else if(trainingnr < 3){
                         Log.d("TrainingControl", "Training is less then 3");
                         //Training +1 if training is less then 3 and the week is less then 10
                         training = "Training " + String.valueOf(trainingnr + 1);
                     }


                 }
                 trainingSelected = "";
                 trainingSelected = week + "_" + training;
                 playTraining();
```

I made the mistake by thinking that != means equal to, but it means NOT equal to, so by replacing the != in the previous post, and editing the code a bit so there can't be negative values any more, THIS WORKS LIKE CHARM NOW!!

Good luck for everybody who needs this!

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you are defining a tree structure, and want to traverse it inorder. This is easiest if the child nodes have a reference to their parent node.

Each node should have an interface to get the next child and get the parent. Once the nodes are implemented you can build your iterator to use them.

Comment: Well that's a little complicated. I mean by this. If the subitem numbers reaches 3 and the next button is clicked, the subitem number is going back to 1 and the item number is going 1 up. Can you post a little code for this? I'll edit my main question with the code i have so far